# Getting the connection pool properties

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, connection-pool

I have set up a connection pool in tomcat's server.xml and context.xml.

I am using the below code to establish a connection.

DataSource ds = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");
ds.getConnection();

Now I want to get the properties like MaxActive, MaxIdle etc. But I don't see any method that can be called using DataSource object. How can I get those parameter values ?